# How to get openssl utilities to accept console input instead of input from file

Tags: console, openssl, utility

A number of openssl.exe utilites as "enc"  accepts on the command line input that indicates where it can find its necessary files. One such a parameter is "-in". For instance "-in c:\temp\key.hex. I would like to type the input from the console. And indeed (on Windows) if you supply all the necessary commandline input except the -in parameter openssl.exe accepts console input. However it does not recognize an end of line (Ctr +Z for instance). So there is no way to end the input. Maybe it is impossible?

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following command in a Windows command prompt:

```
openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -out t.tmp -pass pass:bob
```

Then I typed some input and followed it by **two** `<ctrl>z<enter>` sequences and it terminated.  The subsequent decrypt command successfully decrypted the input.  In Linux, I typed `<ctrl>d` twice (with no enter) and it terminated correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try Ctrl-Z followed by enter to end your input (guessing from memory).

Answer (score 0):

That is not a perfect solution, but it should fit in some cases if your input may include a breakline at the end.

Exemple 1:

```
{ "alg": "ES256", "kid": "ABCDEFG" }
(breakline)
```

In this exemple, in OpenSSL, you type:

> { "alg": "ES256", "kid": "ABCDEFG" }

Followed by "Enter" (the breakline), then "Ctrl+Z", then "Enter" again, that will stop the operation.
In this scenario, the "breakline" will be include in the digest.

On the other hand, if your input must not include a breakline in the end, i don't know the solution...